# Get and post request for the same match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my routes file I have:

```
match 'graphs/(:id(/:action))' => 'graphs#(:action)'
```

and I would like to match this if it is GET request (**working**) or POST request (**not working**)

I know that I can declare POST request inside a resource using:

```
post '/' => :show, :on => :member
```

But how can I do that for a **match** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you want for both POST and GET

```
match 'graphs/(:id(/:action))' => 'graphs#(:action)', :via => [:get, :post]
```

**Edit**

defaults can be set as following

```
match 'graphs/(:id(/:action))' => 'graphs#(:action)', :via => [:get, :post],
                                                      :defaults => { :action => "index" }
```

and the syntax seems to be correct

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is 'graphs#(:action)' a correct syntax? Because :action might exist or might not. Can I somehow specify something as default if :action does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

if you only need the match to respond to a single HTTP verbs or method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH being the most common ones) then using a syntax similar to your "post" example works and is more readable.

match 'graphs/(:id(/:action))' => 'graphs#(:action)'

can become

post 'graphs/(:id(/:action))' => 'graphs#(:action)'
if you want to match and limit to the http POST method.

or

get 'graphs/(:id(/:action))' => 'graphs#(:action)'
if you want to match and limit to the http Get method.

if you need to respond to several http verbs then the "via:" syntax is more readable.